# event with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am a beginner and not familiar with the jquery ui(datepicker).So I have difficult in finishing my exercise.I just want a calendar bind to the events page.Every event has a date and classname ,and then the reference of the date and the classname will be transfered to the datepicker. And at last add different background color to each classname on the datepicker.
thanks!

I wrote a simple code behind.by the way, what i mentioned "events" above just means the "activities"! get the activity's date and classname , then transfer the two reference to datepicker. and then the activity date will display on the calendar and with different background color according to its classname.

```
$(function(){
    var Event = function(text,className){
    this.text = text;
    this.className = className; 
    };
var events = {};
events[new Date("08/08/2012")] = new Event("event_one","pink");
events[new Date("08/12/2012")] = new Event("event_two","green");
events[new Date("08/31/2012")] = new Event("event_three","red");
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay : function(date) {
    var event = events[date];
    if (event) {
        return [true,event.className,event.text];
    }
    else {
        return [true,'',''];
    }
    }
});
});
body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
.demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
.pink > a { 
    background-color: pink !important;
    background-image:none !important;
}
.red > a { 
    background-color: red !important;
    background-image:none !important;
}
.green > a { 
    background-color: green !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

​

Comment: did you write anything allready?

Comment: $(function(){
    var Event = function(text,className){
     this.text = text;
     this.className = className; 
    };
    var events = {};
    events[new Date("08/08/2012")] = new Event("event_one","pink");
    events[new Date("08/12/2012")] = new Event("event_two","green");
    events[new Date("08/31/2012")] = new Event("event_three","red");
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
     beforeShowDay : function(date) {
      var event = events[date];
      if (event) {
       return [true,event.className,event.text];
      }
      else {
       return [true,'',''];
      }
     }
    });
   });

Comment: I wrote this,but this is set the days to event, not get the date and classname reference from different event.because i don't know how to implement the function.

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker have `setDate` method that can be used to set a date in datepicker. [Methods section here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) explained it well.